# WPF Datagrid columns width as percentage of Datagrid ActualWidth

Tags: wpf, datagrid, width, datagridcolumn

I've spent several hours looking at this with no results.

I simply want to have a `DataGrid` with X number of columns that maintains its relative width to the `Grid` itself.

So, for example:

- Col 1: 10%

  Col 2: 10%

  Col 3: 10%

I have set up a style that is attached to a `DataGrid` item template. I have attempted binding the width to the `DataGrid` itself (often a cyclical reference), to another object (the value comes in, but the `DataGridColumn` doesn't update), with a Converter (the converter gets the correct value, then sets the value of the column, but despite different numbers coming back, the width of the column never changes).

I've set up a `SizeChanged` event on the `DataGrid` itself and set the width of the columns specifically, which DID change the values of the columns, but each size event caused another size event, etc... etc...

I'm obviously too stupid to figure this out myself, so if anyone could provide me a simple example of what I imagine *should* be a simple thing to do, I'd be ever so grateful.

So, just to be clear, ALL I'm looking for is a `DataGrid` with X number of columns that maintain a fixed % of the `DataGrid` width itself - pretty much like any table in HTML would do natively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you columns static or dynamic.

Comment: OK...some more information (now that it's later and I've had some time to look at it without my head exploding).

The problem seems to be with the DataGrid inside of a listbox item template. Once in there, it's as if it doesn't get the resize event. The control itself is sized properly, but the columns simply don't update. Hopefully will be able to do a more thorough search now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ColumnWidth` property is your friend.

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*"/>
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer (because it will work), and it turns out my question was badly asked.

I will ask another one which will hopefully help. =)